# How do I loop through image src

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've loaded picture names into a data table on aspx, but is this the best way to put them on the page....

```
    private void LoadPics()
{

    Image1.ImageUrl = @"~\Pictures\" + MyClass.dtprop.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
    Label1.Text = MyClass.dtprop.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
    Image2.ImageUrl = @"~\Pictures\" + MyClass.dtprop.Rows[1]["name"].ToString();
    Label2.Text = MyClass.dtprop.Rows[1]["name"].ToString();
    Image3.ImageUrl = @"~\Pictures\" + MyClass.dtprop.Rows[2]["name"].ToString();
    Label3.Text = MyClass.dtprop.Rows[2]["name"].ToString();
    Image4.ImageUrl = @"~\Pictures\" + MyClass.dtprop.Rows[3]["name"].ToString();
    Label4.Text = MyClass.dtprop.Rows[3]["name"].ToString();
    Image5.ImageUrl = @"~\Pictures\" + MyClass.dtprop.Rows[4]["name"].ToString();
    Label5.Text = MyClass.dtprop.Rows[4]["name"].ToString();
    Image6.ImageUrl = @"~\Pictures\" + MyClass.dtprop.Rows[5]["name"].ToString();
    Label6.Text = MyClass.dtprop.Rows[5]["name"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is there something about this implementation that's not working for you?

Comment: If this code is working but want to get feedback, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

you can try with this code, based on `OfType operator linq`

```
var controls = this.Controls.OfType<Image>();
foreach(var item in controls)
{
  ....
}
```

if you wish add them to page, you can use `PlaceHolder control`

```
Ph.Contols.Add(yourImage);
```

you set your PlaceHolder in the target page

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id ="Ph" runat="server"/>
```

link :http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/bb360913.aspx

Another solution : you can also use `GridView control,` bind this control on your `DataTable` and define `template field`

```
...
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Image id="img" runat="server"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
...
```

Comment: Upvote , i did not knew this this.Controls.OfType<Image>();

Comment: var controls = this.Controls.OfType<Image>(); gets Error 1 'Image' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Drawing.Image' and 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image'

Comment: choose 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image

Comment: still not getting pictures into controls......images are inside a table control......var controls = this.Controls.OfType<System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image>();
        int r = 0; int rl = 0;
        foreach(var item in controls)
        {
              item.ImageUrl = @"~\Pictures\" + MyClass.dtprop.Rows[r]["name"].ToString();
              r++;
        }

Comment: Solved with this    private void LoadPics()
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++)
        {
            int d = c+1;
            string im = "Image" + d.ToString();
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image im1 = Page.FindControl(im) as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image;
            im1.ImageUrl = @"~\Pictures\" + MyClass.dtprop.Rows[c]["name"].ToString(); 
        }